# Why error in Export .avi of Manipulate?

Tags: graphics, manipulate, export, animation

I would like to export to .avi the following Manipulate, but I get a strange output (Abort and black screen). Where am I wrong? The Manipulate works fine, but not the exporting. Basically, the output is a black video after a first good frame. I would also like to to make the arrow head smaller and more suitable to the plot, but didn't succeed.

```
 SetDirectory@NotebookDirectory[];
 epsilon0 = 1/4; 
 zeta0 = 1/4; 
 a = 1;
 b = 1; 
 omega = omeganm[1, 1] - 10^(-10); 
 T = 2 Pi/omega; 
 p0 = 10000; 
 q0 = a^2 b^2 p0/ (B h a b);
 mu = 0.3; (
 k = 7.2*10^7; 
 Erig = 200 10^9; 
 rho = 7800; 
 h = 5*10^-3; 
 B = Erig h^3 /(12 (1 - mu^2)); 
 tau = (rho h a^2 b^2/B)^(1/4);
 alpha = (k/B  a^2 b^2 /4)^(1/4);
 delta = (a^2/b^2);
 omeganm[n_, m_] = Sqrt[Pi^4/tau^4 ((Sqrt[delta] n^2 + m^2/Sqrt[delta])^2 + 4 
 alpha^4/ Pi^4)];
 fnm =  Table[omeganm[n, m]/(2*Pi), {n, 1, 10}, {m, 1, 10}]
 omega11 = omeganm[1, 1] - 10^(-10); 
 T11 = 2 Pi/omega11; 

 etaSerie11a[epsilon_, zeta_, t_] := 
 Sum[2 q0 Sin[
 n Pi 1/2] Sin[
  m Pi 1/2]/(a b tau^4 ((omeganm[n, m] )^2 - omega11^2)) (- 
     omega11/(omeganm[n, m]) Sin[(omeganm[n, m] ) t] + 
  Sin[omega11 t]) (2 Sin[n Pi zeta] Sin[m Pi epsilon]), {n, 1, 
5}, {m, 1, 5}];

Manipulate[
Show[Plot3D[
etaSerie11a[epsilon, zeta, 
 t]/(etaSerie11a[1/2, 1/2, T11/2]), {epsilon, 0, 1}, {zeta, 0, 1},
PlotRange -> {All, All, {-10, 10}}, 
AxesLabel -> {"\[Epsilon]", "\[Zeta]", "z"}, 
PlotLabel -> 
"Plate response (normalized) to a sinusoidal centered force with \
frequency f=" <> ToString[1/T11] <> "Hz", ImageSize -> Large], 
Graphics3D[{Red, Arrowheads[{Automatic, 0.001}], 
Arrow[{{1/2, 
   1/2, (Sin[omega t] 3 Max[etaSerie11a[1/2, 1/2, T11/4]])}, {1/2,
    1/2, 0}}]}]], {t, 0, 6 T11}]

 Export["forzacentro.avi", %]
```

Answer (score 1):

I made some small changes in your code. I have changed the sum range because it was taking to long to export. The code below works fine, you just have to change the path in the `Export` function.

```
epsilon0 = 1/4;
zeta0 = 1/4;
a = 1;
b = 1;
omega = omeganm[1, 1] - 10^(-10);
T = 2 Pi/omega;
p0 = 10000;
q0 = a^2 b^2 p0/(B h a b);
mu = 0.3; (k = 7.2*10^7);
Erig = 200 10^9;
rho = 7800;
h = 5*10^-3;
B = Erig h^3/(12 (1 - mu^2));
tau = (rho h a^2 b^2/B)^(1/4);
alpha = (k/B a^2 b^2/4)^(1/4);
delta = (a^2/b^2);
omeganm[n_, m_] = Sqrt[Pi^4/tau^4 ((Sqrt[delta] n^2 + m^2/Sqrt[delta])^2 + 4 alpha^4/Pi^4)];
fnm = Table[omeganm[n, m]/(2*Pi), {n, 1, 10}, {m, 1, 10}] 
omega11 = omeganm[1, 1] - 10^(-10);
T11 = 2 Pi/omega11;
etaSerie11a[epsilon_, zeta_, t_] := Sum[2 q0 Sin[n Pi 1/2] Sin[m Pi 1/2]/(a b tau^4 ((omeganm[n, m])^2 -omega11^2)) (-omega11/(omeganm[n, m]) Sin[(omeganm[n, m]) t] + Sin[omega11 t]) (2 Sin[n Pi zeta] Sin[m Pi epsilon]), {n, 1, 2}, {m, 1, 2}];
    manipulate = Manipulate[Show[Plot3D[etaSerie11a[epsilon, zeta, t]/(etaSerie11a[1/2, 1/2, T11/2]), {epsilon, 0, 1}, {zeta, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {All, All, {-10, 10}}, 
AxesLabel -> {"\[Epsilon]", "\[Zeta]", "z"}, 
PlotLabel -> 
"Plate response (normalized) to a sinusoidal centered force with \
frequency f=" <> ToString[1/T11] <> "Hz"], 
Graphics3D[{Red, Arrowheads[{Automatic, 0.001}], 
Arrow[{{1/2, 1/2, (Sin[omega t] 3 Max[etaSerie11a[1/2, 1/2, T11/4]])}, {1/2, 1/2, 0}}]}], ImageSize -> Large], {t, 0, 2 T11}] 
    Export["...\\manipulate.avi",manipulate]
```

Comment: did you change only the sum range? Was that the problem?

Comment: @AndreaG i changed the sum range and other small things, like the way to export.

Comment: yes I noticed you just gave a name to the Manipulate: however, I wonder if the reason why my code didn't work was the use of % or the high number of Sum range

Comment: I dont belive it was because of the sum range that it was not working. It was not working because the way to export was given an error `Export::errelem: The Export element GraphicsList contains a malformed data structure and could not be exported to AVI format.`

Comment: I also had the same error, but that happened when I forgot to rerun the manipulate before running Export when in Export one finds %. I am afraid you made the same mistake. However, I have tried increasing the range of Sum and indeed it seems that it goes back not to work. When the range is (1,3) for both n and m, I get a video that is good and then some frames are missing. Things get worse when the range is (1,4) and so on. Bug?